# "config.force_ssl = true" not forcing HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am running Rails 3.1 and have tried putting the above line in development.rb and application .rb (not both at the same time) but it doesn't seem to do anything. My request are still working on HTTP. Isn't this meant to force all requests to use HTTPS? I'm sure I've missed something very obvious here but can't for the life of me think of what - being a newbie doesn't help either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Dany.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you handle SSL in development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118685/how-do-you-handle-ssl-in-development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work locally, have you deployed it?

Comment: What should I expect when it's not working? Will it just leave it on HTTP?

Comment: right, if you run your server locally (localhost:3000) it wont work, try deploying into heroku or something, anyways if you use heroku you'll need an addon (free and payed)

Answer (score 1):

It *will* work provided that your local server (webrick?) is configured to use SSL, below is one way to do that via `script/rails`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

# require 'rubygems'
require 'rails/commands/server'
require 'rack'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'

module Rails
    class Server < ::Rack::Server
        def default_options
            super.merge({
                :Port => 3000,
                :SSLEnable => false, # set to true to automatically generate SSL cert
                :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
                #:SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("ssl.crt").read),
                :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]]
            })
        end
    end
end

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

Comment: This got my server to force redirects to HTTPS, but it looks like some additional SSL cert config is required.