# How do you run Rails with HTTPs locally for testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

Our dev envs use HTTP, prod uses HTTPS, this is causing issues that we can't reproduce locally with are HTTPS related.

How can I run rails with SSL locally for testing purposes? Is there a Webrick config?

Thanks

Comment: I would checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118685/how-do-you-handle-ssl-in-development

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you should to use **thin** to do it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install thin
```

And add this line in config/application.rb

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Then run app on thin with command line:

```
$ thin start --ssl
```

Comment: To install it on all platforms, you can use `gem install thin`.

Comment: Thin doesn't support Rack 3 used by the current Rails versions. I've added an example of running Puma with a self-signed certificate below.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question here is specific to the Rails 'testing' environment, which might mean rspec, and if so, this gist by jaikoo was what worked for me:

https://gist.github.com/jaikoo/daf88024b8de1cf9339b

With respect to the 'development' environment, ultimately I used thin, which I didn't really want to, but the best write-up of that I saw was this post by Keyur Gohil:

https://blog.botreetechnologies.com/enable-ssl-in-developement-using-thin-2a4bd1af500d

Though I put it in a batch file and added -D -V and made sure it ran on a different port:

```
#!
#  Sets up the use of SSL in development
#
# https://www.devmynd.com/blog/rails-local-development-https-using-self-signed-ssl-certificate/
#
bundle exec thin -D -V start -a localhost -p 3001 --ssl --ssl-key-file ~/development/apps/localhost_ssl_tsl_keys/localhost.key --ssl-cert-file ~/development/apps/localhost_ssl_tsl_keys/localhost.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

For the current Rails versions (using Rack 3 and Puma as the default web server), the easiest way I could find was to:

1. Create self-signed certificate:

   openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt
2. Start Puma:

   puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:9292?key=localhost.key&cert=localhost.crt&verify_mode=none'

Answer (score -21):

Ultimately, you should be running development without SSL, period. Unless something is wrong with your SSL Cert, you should not have errors that are independent of the different environments.

Staging is where you would test the SSL framework.

Comment: And what if what you are testing actually depends on HTTPS? For example, my site has a different flow if you click "login" when you are on http or https. So it actually makes a lot of sense to want to run your app in HTTPS locally.

Comment: There absolutely valid reasons to try running SSL locally. The OPs use case is a perfect example.