# In development, how can I redirect to https using a self-signed certificate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https

How can I redirect www.example.com to https://www.example.com?

I'm doing this in development and I'm using a self-signed certificate. I added `config.force_ssl = true` in my application.rb and added a before_filter callback with this method in my application controller:

```
def redirect_secure
    redirect_to protocol: "https" if request.protocol == "http" 
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you handle SSL in development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118685/how-do-you-handle-ssl-in-development)

Answer (score 1):

For server ssl certificate configuration for development add following codes to script/rails file,

```
module Rails
    class Server < ::Rack::Server
        def default_options
            super.merge({
                :Port => 3445,
                :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
                :daemonize => false,
                :debugger => false,
                :pid => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
                :config => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
                :SSLEnable => true,
                :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
                :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(
                       File.open("/home/mohanraj/myCA/server_key.pem").read),
                :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
                       File.open("/home/mohanraj/myCA/server_crt.pem").read),
                :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]]
            })
        end
    end
end
```

NOTE: please give correct path for ssl files.

Please follow this link for redirection http://www.railway.at/2013/02/12/using-ssl-in-your-local-rails-environment/

Comment: Is monkeypatching the ActionController::ForceSSL the last resort to solve this problem? I've read in this post: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5023 that devs are saying that SSL should not be disabled by default in any environment. By any chance, does any one know if there's an update with this request?